# Does a 304 response count toward api-usage count?

Tags: rest-api, governorlimits, limits

When making an API call with `If-Modified-Since` header - if the response returns with a `304-Not Modified` will that use one of my call allocation?

Also can the `If-Modified-Since` if supplied in a list or record request check that whole item or collection before returning.

Answer (score 0):

If-Modified-Since header counts against your daily Api limits. This can be verified by the Limit info header. ([More details here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/headers_api_usage.htm))